# On minimal generating sets of a group

Tags: group-theory

I've been stuck on this problem:

Prove or disprove: Any generating set of a group must contain a minimal generating set.

What if the group is finite? Does the statement hold?

Here, a minimal generating set is a generating set such that any of its proper subsets generates a proper subgroup of the group.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Prufer $p$-group?

Answer (score 2):

By Zorn's Lemma, the only way this can be false is if there exists a group $G$ with an infinite descending chain of generating subsets which has no lower bound (in the poset of generating subsets of $G$).

So, consider a descending chain $S_1 \supseteq S_2 \supseteq \cdots$ of generating subsets of a group $G$. If this has a lower bound $T$, then $S := \bigcap_i S_i$ must also be a lower bound: this is because $T \subseteq S$, whence $S$ generates $G$. Thus, a descending chain $S_1 \supseteq S_2 \supseteq \cdots$ of generating subsets of a group $G$ has a lower bound if and only if $\bigcap_i S_i$ generates $G$.

Now the question becomes: if $S_1 \supseteq S_2 \supseteq \cdots$ is a descending chain of generating sets of $G$, must $\bigcap_i S_i$ generate $G$?

Hint: if $G$ is nontrivial and $\bigcap_i S_i = \varnothing$, then the answer is "no".